# Android ImageView location changes when device orientation changes

Tags: android, imageview, orientation

I'm developing my own gallery for my APP (since Gallery widget has been deprecated...)

All 3rd party libraries I used for this are as follows:

- [HorizontalPager](https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager/)
- [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/)

Problem I'm facing is when screen orientation changed, my ImageView will not keep in center of screen. It just moved to another location, maybe top-left, or some others.

Here are my screen shot.

Before orientation change:

[image]

After orientation change:

[image]

Here is key-part of my layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#FF000000" android:keepScreenOn="true">
  <!-- I want my title bar and control bar in front of MorizontalPager -->
  <com.github.ysamlan.horizontalpager.HorizontalPager android:id="@+id/hPager" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
  </com.github.ysamlan.horizontalpager.HorizontalPager>

  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/head" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/head_bar" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnBack" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="12sp" android:background="@drawable/btn_back" android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtFolder" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="18sp" android:text="@string/app_name" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:layout_weight="1" android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnMenu" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/btn_menu" />
  </LinearLayout>
  ...some more...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Part of my activity:

```
private HorizontalPager hPager=null;
hPager=(HorizontalPager)findViewById(R.id.hPager);

...some code...

private void loadPhotos()
{
  for(int i=0; i<Constants.PHOTO_LIST.size(); i++)
  {
    ImageView img=new ImageView(this);
    LayoutParams lp=new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    img.setLayoutParams(lp);
    img.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    img.setMaxWidth(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH);
    img.setMaxHeight(Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
//      img.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    img.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
    img.setClickable(true);
    img.setFocusable(true);
    img.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
        isControlShow=!isControlShow;
        if(isControlShow)
        {
          head.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          foot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
          head.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          foot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
      }
    });
    img.setOnTouchListener(new MultiPointTouchListener());
    hPager.addView(img);
    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Preparing photo: "+i);
    imageLoaderSet(Constants.PHOTO_LIST.get(i).getFileId(), img);
  }
  hPager.setOnScreenSwitchListener(onScreenSwitchListener);
  hPager.setCurrentScreen(currentIndex, true);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  return;
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
  super.onResume();
  Log.i(Constants.TAG, "on PhotoShow resume...");
  loadPhotos();
}
```

Until now, I still don't know what makes this problem occurred, hope someone can show me some tips.

Comment: <com.github.ysamlan.horizontalpager.HorizontalPager android:id="@+id/hPager" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" /> **try this code..** instead your in xml file

Comment: this is weird since by default the activity is recreated from scratch on rotation. therefore the image should be centered after rotation. are you sure you don't have `android:configChanges` (or something similar) set in the manifest?

Comment: for com.github.ysamlan.horizontalpager.HorizontalPager set attribute:     aligncenterinparent="true"

Comment: Set android:layout_height="wrap_content" makes HorizontalPager throw this exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewSwitcher can only be used in EXACTLY mode.
at com.github.ysamlan.horizontalpager.HorizontalPager.onMeasure(HorizontalPager.java:137)

Also tried to set android:layout_height="0dip" (SDK suggest this to instead wrap_content),
that makes HorizontalPager invisible...:-(
////
Another try, add android:layout_centerInParent="true" to HorizontalPager, didn’t help...:-(

Comment: BTW, I tried this code
ImageView img=new ImageView(this);
LayoutParams lp=new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
img.setLayoutParams(lp);
...
hPager.addView(img);

Makes no effect as well.

Comment: I finally realize what cause this problem occurred, my "MultiPointTouchListener" bring suck things to me, take me 3 days to know. I may have to find new 2 finger image zoom solution... :-(